# Java - Update attributes of an object from a different class with protected methods

Tags: java, methods, attributes

I am trying to swap pieces (or cells) in a grid.

I have the class Cell with attributes such as coordinate (position in the board). This class has the method setCoordinate as protected.

I also have the class Level, with attributes such as board (composed by many objects of the class Cell), and a method to swap pieces. It also has a method like getCell, to retrieve the cell object given a coordinate in the grid.

So, if I create a cell object such as:

```
Cell cell1 = (Cell) getCell(new Coordinate(2, 2));
Cell cell2 = (Cell) getCell(new Coordinate(1, 1));
```

When I swap pieces

```
    public void swapCells(Coordinate firstCoord, Coordinate secondCoord) {
          setCell(secondCoord,getCell(firstCoord));
          setCell(firstCoord,getCell(secondCoord));
}
```

I can place cell1 in cell2's spot, and cell2 in cell1's spot. However, the coordinates of each cell do not update according to the new position in the board.

I cannot use the method setCoordinate from class Cell because it is protected, and I cannot create a public method. I am not sure of the reason, but I am still learning and this is a requirement that is given.

How could I achieve a swap in which coordinates are updated too?

Here are some relevant and simplified parts of my code:

```
public class Level {
   
    private Cell[][] board;

   
    public Level(String fileName) {
       
        parse(fileName);
    }

 
    private void parse(String fileName) {
        ... fills board...
    }

   

    public Cell getCell(Coordinate coord) {
        return board[coord.getRow()][coord.getColumn()];
        } 
   

    private void setCell(Coordinate coord, Cell cell) {
        
            board[coord.getRow()][coord.getColumn()] = cell;       
    }

    public void swapCells(Coordinate firstCoord, Coordinate secondCoord) {
        
            setCell(secondCoord,getCell(firstCoord));
            setCell(firstCoord,getCell(secondCoord)); 
        } 
    }
}


public class Cell {

    private Coordinate coordinate;

    public Cell(int row, int column) {
        setCoordinate(row,column);
    }

    public Coordinate getCoordinate() { return this.coordinate; }

    protected void setCoordinate(int row, int column) {
        this.coordinate = new Coordinate(row,column);
    }

}


public class Coordinate {
    private int row;
    private int column;

    public Coordinate(int row, int column) {
        setRow(row);
        setColumn(column);
    }

    public int getRow() { return this.row; };

    private void setRow(int row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

    public int getColumn() {return this.column; }

    private void setColumn(int column) {
        this.column = column;
    }

}
```

**Edit:**
After looking into it more, it seems my problem is that when I do the swap, I assign a new piece to a cell in the board, instead of really swaping. The final board is correct, but I keep recreating pieces instead of swaping.

So, a bit simplified, to swap piece in (0,0) with piece in (1,1) I do:

```
board[0][0] = getCell(1,1);
board[1][1] = getCell(0,0);
```

But with this I am creating new pieces for selected positions.

What I have in the test is something like:

```
Cell cell1 = getCell(0,0);
Cell cell2 = getCell(1,1);

swapCells(cell1.getCoordinate(), cell2.getCoordinate());

assertEquals("(1,1)", cell1.getCoordinate().toString());
```

But the assertequals fails because they are on these objects cell1 and cell2, but I am not really using the objects, just creating new ones that look like them. Also, the swapCells method doesn't have Cell objects as arguments. I really can't see how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems to solve.

1. Changing the location of a `Cell` object in the `board` array.
2. Update the internal data of a `Cell` object upon a swap.

The first you have done already. To achieve the 2nd you need to be able to do at least one of the options below.

1. Have access to method that update the data, or
2. Have a delegate object that can update the data for you, or
3. Give the illusion that a swap has taken place, or
4. Use reflection (not recommended)

You mentioned that you are restricted by a given requirement that you cannot change access to the needed methods. Therefore, this is not an option.

Creating a delegate object (in this context) mean that you will need to extend `Cell` class and allow access to its protected methods through the child class. This seems like a hack to me. I don't think this is the right way to do this, but it will allow you to have access without truly violating your requirements.

The third option is what I think you should to. To do this, all you need to do is create copies of the original objects and place them where they need to go. For example, place the copy of cell two where cell one is and the copy of cell one where cell two is located.

The fourth option I am not even going to explain. But, using reflection, you will be able to bypass access restrictions and manipulate the protected data. You can read about reflection if you would like. But, regardless of my personal views on reflection, it is an option that will allow you to achieve what you want.

**UPDATE**: When swapping two elements in an array, you need to implement this simple 3-step process:

1. Store element 1 in a TEMPORARY variable.
2. Store element 2 in element 1's location. (element 2 becomes element 1)
3. Store TEMPORARY variable in element 2's location (old element 1 becomes element 2).

If you don't store the first element into a temporary variable, you will overwrite the first element's data. In your case, that will look something like this:

```
public void swapCells(Coordinate firstCoord, Coordinate secondCoord) {
    
    Cell temp = getCell(secondCoord); // Saves second cell temporarily

    setCell(secondCoord, getCell(firstCoord)); // Saves first cell into second cell's location
    setCell(firstCoord, temp); // Sets the temp cell (second cell) into the first cell's location
}
```

Also, because you have access to the `Cell` object, you can set the coordinates even if the method is protected. Therefore, your setter method should be something like this:

```
private void setCell(Coordinate coord, Cell cell) {
    
    cell.setCoordinate(coord.getRow(), coord.getColumn());
    board[coord.getRow()][coord.getColumn()] = cell;
}
```

I added a "name" attribute to the `Cell` class to make it easier to debug (for you). Now, when I run your code with the two changes I made, you can see that "cell0" which used to be (0,0) is now (2,2) and cell8 is now (0,0); showing that the two cells swapped places AND updated their respective coordinate fields as well.

[image]

The `main` method I executed for this is the one below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Level level = new Level("Level1");
    int count = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++ ) {
            Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate(row, col);
            Cell cell = new Cell(row, col, "cell" + count++);
            level.setCell(coordinate, cell);
        }
    }
    
    level.swapCells(new Coordinate(0,0), new Coordinate(2,2));
}
```

Comment: Thank you @hfontanez
I am studying the third option. If I create a copy, won't the attribute coordinate stay the same? 
So if I create A in position (1,1), I will get (1,1) when I do A.getCoordinate().
If I move it to (2,2), I want to get (2,2) when I do A.getCoordinate().

Comment: @sapehi I suggest you sketch it first. It helps to visualize the problem and the solution before you start writing code, especially if the problem is hard or you are not familiarized with a particular technology.

Comment: @sapehi is this a homework problem? If it is, it helps if you let us know what is the topic you are learning so we could frame an answer appropriate to the topic. If it is not, you may want to consider researching about overriding `Object#equals(Object)` method.

Comment: It is for school and a final project, but not focused on something specific. I am gonna add some more details to the post

Comment: If `Coordinate` is a required field of `Cell` (injected via constructor), why do you need to pass a `Coordinate` object to `setCell` method in `Level`? The setter method could just get the `Cell` and extract the coordinates where it needs to be set from the cell object itself.

Comment: There are a few things wrong with your code, but the issue with `swap` seems pretty bad. That said, you still need to figure out how to update the data inside `Cell`

Comment: Thank you, I'll work on it with your comments. Also the methods and arguments are given to us, we only need to code the bodies. I will look into setCell further

Comment: @sapehi You could also update the cells in place, but that is a bit more complicated given your requirements. What I provided to you works good and doesn't violate any of your requirements.

Comment: @sapehi don't forget to upvote my answer if it was helpful and to select it as the answer if I completely answered your question. ;)

Comment: I totally will @hfontanez, I'm just not able to use setCoordinate in setCell so still thinking about it, but I'm finding all of this really helpful and I'm grateful :)